# How can I change background color and add custom font into my introduction scene in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a quotes app for my practice project in flutter.In the beginning i added a custom text animation  as  an introduction.I did not create it by myself,as i am a beginner.I took help from  The web,while creating that animation.Though it looks fine,it seems very plain and colorless.How can i add Custom font in those text?.And add a coloured background too.

```
class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_IntroScreenState createState() => _IntroScreenState();
}

 class _IntroScreenState extends State<IntroScreen> {
 static const _titles = <String>[
"Covid-19 made us \nuneasy",
"Focus on what is \nimportant for you",
"Create a task and \nlet the bubbles pop",
 ];

 Timer timer;
 int index =0;
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:3), (timer){
   if(index< titles.length -1){
     setState(() {
       index++;
     });
   }
   if(index == titles.length -1){
    timer.cancel();
    print("Done");
   }
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Center(
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          child:Text(
            titles[index],
            key:ValueKey(titles[index]),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 34,
         right: 34,
         child: TextButton(onPressed: () {} ,
             child: Text("Skip", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
         ) ,
        )
        ]
        )
        );
        }
        @override
        void dispose(){
        timer.cancel();
        super.dispose();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download custom font from this [link](https://fonts.google.com/) ,then please add this font files in one folder in your project
Assign path for that font file into pubspec.yaml file like below.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Asap
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Asap-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/Asap-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: fonts/Asap-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/Asap-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Now you can use this custom font in your project as below.

```
theme: ThemeData(
         fontFamily: 'Asap',
       ),
```

Please put above code in Material App Widget.

If you want to use this font only for specific text then you need to use it as below.

```
style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Asap')
```

For background color you can use color property of material widget.